# Is there a module that creates an input filter to convert text to the ASCII character-set?

Tags: input-formats

I have a textarea on a content type that needs to be converted ASCII character-set. Is there an available module that adds a input filter for this? This field needs to be fed to another platform with this formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the [Transliteration](https://drupal.org/project/transliteration) module installed, you can create your own filter.

Go to `/admin/config/content/formats` and click on *Add text format* at the top. One of the options is *Convert all characters to US-ASCII*. Set the roles you want to allow use of the format and save.